# Copy data to another spreadsheet based off value stored in string

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have the below code for one of my financial reports and I'm struggling with updating the code to make it more automated. The code creates a string of the column headers stored in multiple sheets. Each column header is a new tab in wb2. I can't figure out how to get formulas copied into a new address range. it needs to copy the values to that Sheet in wb2 and then move on to the next.

So the code needs to:
1/put the column headers to a string/array [Works]
2/look through string/array and find that column in wb1 [Works]
3/then copy specific ranges to wb2 (name is based of column header/string value) [Works]
4/copy formula into column G, based on row similar to what it does for column A addresses - for example if the range is G9, it needs to copy the formula H9-A9, etc
5/go to next value

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
Sub Prepare_CYTD_Report()
Dim addresses() As String
Dim addresses2() As String
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim my_Filename

'Declare variables for MHP60
Dim i As Long, lastcol As Long
Dim tabNames As Range, cell As Range, tabName As String
'Declare variables for MHP61
Dim i2 As Long, lastCol2 As Long
Dim tabNames2 As Range, cell2 As Range, tabName2 As String
'Declare variables for MHP62
Dim i3 As Long, lastCol3 As Long
Dim tabNames3 As Range, cell3 As Range, tabName3 As String


addresses = Strings.Split("A9,A12:A26,A32:A38,A42:A58,A62:A70,A73:A76,A83:A90", ",") 'Trial Balance string values
addresses2 = Strings.Split("G9,G12:G26,G32:G38,G42:G58,G62:G70,G73:G76,G83:G90", ",")  'Prior Month string values

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook    'Trial Balance to Financial Statements Workbook

'*****************************Load Column Header Strings
lastcol = wb1.Sheets("MHP60").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
On Error Resume Next
Set tabNames = wb1.Sheets("MHP60").Cells(4, 3).Resize(1, lastcol - 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
'actual non-formula text values on row 4 from column C up to column lastCol'
On Error GoTo 0
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "No headers were found on row 4 of MHP60", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

lastCol2 = wb1.Sheets("MHP61").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
On Error Resume Next
Set tabNames2 = wb1.Sheets("MHP61").Cells(4, 3).Resize(1, lastcol - 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
'actual non-formula text values on row 4 from column C up to column lastCol'
On Error GoTo 0
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "No headers were found on row 4 of MHP61", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

lastCol3 = wb1.Sheets("MHP62").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
On Error Resume Next
Set tabNames3 = wb1.Sheets("MHP62").Cells(4, 3).Resize(1, lastcol - 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
'actual non-formula text values on row 4 from column C up to column lastCol'
On Error GoTo 0
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "No headers were found on row 4 of MHP62", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

'*****************************Open CYTD/FYTD files
my_Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*", Title:="Select File to create Reports")

If my_Filename = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(my_Filename)

'*****************************Copy values to Financial statements workbook
For Each cell In tabNames
    tabName = Strings.Trim(cell.Value2)
    'dedicated variable in case of requirement for further parsing (space/comma elimination?)'
    If CStr(wb1.Sheets("MHP60").Evaluate("ISREF('[" & wb2.Name & "]" & tabName & "'!$A$1)")) = "True" Then
    'If wb2 has a tab named for the value in tabName
        For i = 0 To UBound(addresses)
            wb2.Sheets(tabName).Range(addresses(i)).Value2 = wb1.Sheets("MHP60").Range(addresses(i)).Offset(0, cell.Column - 1).Value2
            'wb2.Sheets(tabName).Range(addresses2(i)).Value2 =
            'Debug.Print "data for " & wb2.Sheets(tabName).Range(addresses(i)).Address(, , , True) & " copied from " & wb1.Sheets("MHP60").Range(addresses(i)).Offset(0, cell.Column - 1).Address(, , , True)
        Next i
    Else
        Debug.Print "A tab " & tabName & " was not found in " & wb2.Name
    End If
Next cell

For Each cell In tabNames2
    tabName2 = Strings.Trim(cell.Value2)
    'dedicated variable in case of requirement for further parsing (space/comma elimination?)'
    If CStr(wb1.Sheets("MHP61").Evaluate("ISREF('[" & wb2.Name & "]" & tabName2 & "'!$A$1)")) = "True" Then
    'If wb2 has a tab named for the value in tabName
        For i = 0 To UBound(addresses)
            wb2.Sheets(tabName2).Range(addresses(i)).Value2 = wb1.Sheets("MHP61").Range(addresses(i)).Offset(0, cell.Column - 1).Value2
            'Debug.Print "data for " & wb2.Sheets(tabName2).Range(addresses(i)).Address(, , , True) & " copied from " & wb1.Sheets("MHP61").Range(addresses(i)).Offset(0, cell.Column - 1).Address(, , , True)
        Next i
    Else
        Debug.Print "A tab " & tabName2 & " was not found in " & wb2.Name
    End If
Next cell

For Each cell In tabNames3
    tabName3 = Strings.Trim(cell.Value2)
    'dedicated variable in case of requirement for further parsing (space/comma elimination?)'
    If CStr(wb1.Sheets("MHP62").Evaluate("ISREF('[" & wb2.Name & "]" & tabName3 & "'!$A$1)")) = "True" Then
    'If wb2 has a tab named for the value in tabName
        For i = 0 To UBound(addresses)
            wb2.Sheets(tabName3).Range(addresses(i)).Value2 = wb1.Sheets("MHP62").Range(addresses(i)).Offset(0, cell.Column - 1).Value2
            'Debug.Print "data for " & wb2.Sheets(tabName2).Range(addresses(i)).Address(, , , True) & " copied from " & wb1.Sheets("MHP62").Range(addresses(i)).Offset(0, cell.Column - 1).Address(, , , True)
        Next i
    Else
        Debug.Print "A tab " & tabName3 & " was not found in " & wb2.Name
    End If
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: You strip space characters out of each element of your array, but the 3 sheets to which you're writing data _all_ contain a space character - why do you do this when it means that a given array element will not match up with a worksheet name?

Comment: trying to understand: lastCol60 is the last column used at row 5 ( i am assuming that this is the row where your headers are located) but then in your array MHP60 you enter values from row 4. is this intended? also you probably want to initialize j=1 before looping

Comment: I'm not very vba friendly. I found the code an manipulated it, but the headers are stored in row 4. I found the code from another post and tried to manipulate it to fit my needs. I was unsuccessful.

Comment: The code I posted in my answer _does_ read the headers from row *4*, if there are issues with it then please add a comment to the answer

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I have other tabs to read in also, but they are all formatted the exact same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Prepare_CYTD_Report()
    Dim addresses() As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim i As Long, lastCol As Long, my_FileName
    Dim tabNames As Range, cell As Range, tabName As String
    
    addresses = Strings.Split("A12:A26,A32:A38,A42:A58,A62:A70,A73:A76,A83:A90", ",")
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook    'Trial Balance to Financial Statements
    lastCol = wb1.Sheets("MHP60").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tabNames = wb1.Sheets("MHP60").Cells(4, 3).Resize(1, lastCol - 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'actual non-formula text values on row 4 from column C up to column lastCol'
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "No headers were found on row 4 of MHP60", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '*****************************Open CYTD/FYTD files
    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

    If my_FileName = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(my_FileName)
    
    For Each cell In tabNames
        tabName = Strings.Trim(cell.Value2)
        'dedicated variable in case of requirement for further parsing (space/comma elimination?)'
        If CStr(wb2.Worksheets(1).Evaluate("ISREF('" & tabName & "'!$A$1)")) = "True" Then
        'If wb2 has a tab named for the value in tabName
            For i = 0 To UBound(addresses)
                wb2.Sheets(tabName).Range(addresses(i)).Value2 = wb1.Sheets("MHP60").Range(addresses(i)).Offset(0, cell.Column - 1).Value2
                'Debug.Print "data for " & wb2.Sheets(tabName).Range(addresses(i)).Address(, , , True) & " copied from " & wb1.Sheets("MHP60").Range(addresses(i)).Offset(0, cell.Column - 1).Address(, , , True)
            Next i
        Else
            Debug.Print "A tab " & tabName & " was not found in " & wb2.Name
        End If
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In view of the observation made in my comment, the code presented above assumes that

- the actual cell values on row 4 of *MHP60* are the values 'as is' of
  the actual tab names
- those cell values were manually entered, i.e. not formula-driven

Comment: SpectralInstance, this worked perfectly. To future add on to this, I created an address2() because in each of those same tabs, I need to paste a simple formula into column G, same ranges as addresses() G12:G26, etc. the formula takes H12-A12, could i added that into the for look to write that formula? Sorry if this should have been another post, just figured its a quick update to the loop.

Comment: Please edit your original Q, where you had examples for 3 tabs, so that I can see where you want the formula and, more importantly, what the formula definition actually is.

Comment: I updated the new code above. Similar to how it runs through the addresses() string and copies values from one workbook to another. the addresses2 needs to hold formulas for the respective rows. i.e. G9 formula should be H9-A9. Hope I explained that correct. And I really appreciate all your help. I'm a beginner VBA'er and I've learned so much from your code. :)

Comment: Sorry, but you've (effectively) replaced your Q with what you think it should look like - I meant for you to edit your original Q (which had 3 examples) so that I could what adding the formulas manually would look like (it was by seeing that 'pattern' in your original Q that I figured out what you wanted, so I need to be able to see the 'pattern' for your formulas)

Comment: Sorry. Guess I messed that one up. I don't have the original code anymore. I can post another question utilizing this code.

Comment: I think I know now what you want, assuming you're talking about a `SUM()` formula; trouble is that having a formula in G9 that sums A9:H9 results in a circular reference(!)

Comment: The formula in G9 should be the value stored in H9 minus the value stored in A9, formula in G12 would be H12 minus A12 etc. I just need the code to write the formula there somehow. Right now I manuall my have to go in each tab and put the formula in.

Comment: Ok, so the line you want to add is `wb2.Sheets(tabName).Range(addresses2(i)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]-RC[-6]"`

Comment: That would involve writing a new procedure, such that it should be a NEW question - you would also have to include, in that question, your actual formulae from columns A and H, since the formula e.g. =H9-A9 (where H9 already references A9) does not _automatically_ create a circular reference.

Comment: thanks again. the more i look into, the more complicated its getting.

Comment: Just tried something, so maybe this will work for you `wb2.Sheets(tabName).Range(addresses2(i)).Value2 = wb2.Sheets(tabName).Evaluate(Range(addresses2(i)).Offset(0,1).Address & " - " & Range(addresses2(i)).Offset(0,-6).Address)`

Comment: i have a quick question. I just duplicated your code to copy an additional address string `addresses2 = Strings.Split("I9,I12:I26,I32:I38,I42:I58,I62:I70,I73:I76,I83:I90", ",")` the copying to the file part works fine, but its copying the wrong column values. I know it has to do with my offset. its supposed to paste the values to column I in wb2, but it should read the values starting at column B in wb1.

Comment: You'll need to experiment, i.e. `Range(addresses2(i)).Offset(0,-7)` would point to column B, but you probably need the `7` to be determined dynamically, and there isn't enough information for me to do that.